# Scrolling effect on click on a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a scrolling effect to a menu. To be precise i want to click on a image and when i click it the menu to scroll down by 1 with a fade effect or what ever effect to the next link. 
Ahhh...Like a windmill wheel if u understand what i mean.:)
And couldn't find any info.

Here is my code :

```
    <div class=".img-fade"><img src="http://www.lahondafire.org/nest/Volunteer%20Manual/Signs%20and%20Forms/Arrow.gif" width="180" height="170"><BR>
When i click on the arrow the links below start scrolling down by 1 and contact to be top and about me to be to bottom...</div>
        <div class="menu">
    <a HREF="#">About me</a><BR>
    <a HREF="#">Portofolio</a><Br>
    <a HREF="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WCtQn/242/

So when i click on that arrow to move the links from top to bottom or bottom to top,dosen't matter.

Thank you.

Comment: show us what you have done so far??not just the html...javascript alsoo

Comment: forgot to mention another thing i didn't know what function to call? can any1 give me something to look upon ? Should i go with scrollto.+1 ?

Comment: So you want to change the order of the links when the arrow is clicked?

Comment: So do you want the items to reorder when the arrow is clicked? As in each moves up one and the top one goes to the bottom?

Comment: Yes exactly! when i click the order to change.

Comment: I dont see any code related to jQuery or js?  both here and fiddle.

Comment: [You're going to need to stub out your functionality and show some work before getting any real help on this one.. at least from me.](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @ЗапорожанВиктор Did you end up resolving your issue?

Comment: Thank you all,forgot for some time to post an update on this one but the problem was solved.Thank you all so much and sorry for the delayd respond. I've uised something similar to you below.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this method](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/WCtQn/246/). It reorders the list elements when the arrow is clicked

```
$('.img-fade').click(function() {
    var last = $('a')[0];
    last.remove();
    $('br')[0].remove();
    $('.menu').append("<br> " + last['outerHTML']);
});
```

You should learn how to use javascript/jQuery and show us what you've tried so far and what you're having trouble with next time you post here

If you want something fancier you could look to do something similar to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vyhph/), though I'd add some `.stop()`s to remove some errors it has

Answer (score 0):

I'm no jQuery pro but I've come up with something that is close to what you're looking for.  I spiced it up with a fade effect.  I also removed the `<br>` tags and set the links to `display: block;`.  You could modify what I have to something similar to what @Zeaklous has posted to remove them along with the element and add them back in.

http://jsfiddle.net/WCtQn/248/

```js
$('.img-fade').on('click', 'img', function(){

      var firstItem = $('.menu a').first();
      firstItem.fadeOut(2000, function() {
           $(this).remove();
           $('.menu').append(firstItem);
           $('.menu a').last().fadeIn(2000);
      });

});
```

Comment: You need to update your jsfiddle (: I might also speed it up a bit